# Laravel Tracker Package User Model Misses Admin/Authentication Issue

Tags: laravel, tracker

I've installed the laravel tracker package by antonioribeiro from [here](https://github.com/antonioribeiro/tracker)

I also installed the stats panel. When I first went to the panel, it said 'authentication required'. So I searched around and found [this](https://github.com/antonioribeiro/tracker/issues/165) issue, so I changed that line.

Now when I go to the /stats page on my website, I get the error 'User model misses admin property'.

But my model has that.  I have put in the admin property just as instructed on the install page

```
public function getIsAdminAttribute() {
    return true;
}
```

It appears that tracker is working. I can echo out $tracker = Tracker::currentSession() and everything works there.

I've changed the user models in the tracker config file and enabled the stats panel.

I can't figure out what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

@Nertskull 
You have to change the line 491 of the file vendor\pragmarx\tracker\src\Vendor\Laravel\ServiceProvider to add the web middleware :

```
$router->group(['prefix' => $prefix, 'middleware' => 'web'], function($router)
```

Comment: I actually already have done that. It was the 2nd link in my post about the issue I found and fixed. But having changed that, I still get that the admin attribute isn't set, even though it is.